# Javascript Cookies not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari

I've been trying to implement a basic cookie storage function in Javascript, which works as intended in most browsers, but not Safari (8.0.3). I've stripped it down to the below example, where every other browser changes the text to the date that is stored in the cookie, but Safari doesn't store a cookie at all and gives out an empty string (no error messages in the console either). Safari is set to accept all cookies.

If I enter the code in the testbed at W3Schools.com, it works in every browser, so is it somehow related to the domain? (In JSFiddle it doesn't seem to work at all, with the console complaining that myFunction is not defined.)

I've only found two older problems of the same type, but in one case the solution was adding the "; path=/" part, which is already in here, and in the other there was a comma in place of a semicolon.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="doesitwork" onclick="myFunction()">Does it work?</p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    d = new Date();
    document.cookie = (d + "; expires=" + "May 31 2016 23:59:59 GMT+09:00" + "; path=/");
    var x = document.cookie;
    document.getElementById("doesitwork").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are not setting a name value pair

```
document.cookie = (d + "; expires=" + "May 31 2016 23:59:59 GMT+09:00" + "; path=/");
```

should be something like

```
document.cookie = "time=" + d + "; expires=" + "May 31 2016 23:59:59 GMT+09:00" + "; path=/";
```

Comment: Oh thanks, that did the job. I guess the other browsers just interpret it as desired without the name part by default. Curious that it would still work in the W3Schools simulation in Safari, but not in a life setting...

Comment: Not working in mobile browser also not working in mac os safari

Comment: @MayankDudakiya I had same issue with Safari, so in the end I opted for sessionStorage instead, which works on Safari. You can look it up on MDN there's a nice guide on how to use sessionStorage

Answer (score 7):

By default cookie not allowed for iOS safari browser. We have to enable cookies setting from safari browser

So we have implemented local storage(javascript concept)to overcome the cookie problems in safari browser.

Comment: So what do you suggest

Comment: i suggest localstorage concept https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local
this will help you to overcome cookie concept

Comment: what is the defferent between it and cookie ? and does it work with all platforms ?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi I see you still have not been answered. Localstorage persists when you remove your cookies, stores more data (5mb I believe) and has some security improvements.

Comment: But localstorage doesnt support cross domain jwt auth

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [this nice article](http://clubmate.fi/setting-and-reading-cookies-with-javascript/) and they show you a function for creating, reading and deleting cookies also it shows pure JS and jQuery. The code on the blog is shown like so:

```
// Create cookie
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

// Read cookie
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// Erase cookie
function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Creating cookies like this:

```
createCookie("cookie-name", "cookie-value", 30);
```

Reading cookie like this:

```
readCookie("cookie-name");
// Usually you set it as a variable and then use it somewhere
var colorTheme = readCookie("color-theme");
// Then do some conditional crap with it
if (colorTheme == "Blue") {
    // Add a class to the body or elswere
} else {
    // Add a different class maybe...
}
```

Comment: In my case in Safari, I was not able to delete cookies on the client, but erasing them in the backend somehow worked

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was not able to save the cookie in the Safari browser. It was because of the security.

I included the **SameSite** attribute with the value "**Lax**" for improved security. The **path** attribute is also set to "/", making the cookie accessible across your entire website.

Below is the code I added for setting the cookie.

```
var year = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2;
var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + year);

document.cookie = "cookiename=value; expires=" + expires.toUTCString() + "; path=/; SameSite=Lax";
```