# document write cookie is not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari

I want to overwrite exisiting cookie value;

on Chrome, following JS in browser allows to overwrite/update exisiting cookie

`document.cookie = "test=poppy; path=/; secure; domain=.mytest.com"`

but on Safari(14.1.1), above JS script does NOT overwrite/update exisiting cookie.

Anyone knows why ? or any good explanation please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript cookies on Safari require a name-value pair for each of the sections. This should work.

```
document.cookie = "test=poppy; path=/; name=secure; domain=.mytest.com"
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087869/javascript-cookies-not-working-in-safari/37087962)

That article also describes that localstorage would be a better place to store this information to work on iOS Safari where cookies have not been enabled (they default to disabled).