# Safari not saving cookie value correctly

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari

I got a JSON I need to save in cookies:

```
{
   "0":{
      "question":"intro 1",
      "type":"1"
   },
   "5":{
      "question":"extro 1",
      "type":"0"
   },
   "7":{
      "question":"extro 3",
      "type":"0"
   },
   "8":{
      "question":"extro 4",
      "type":"0"
   },
   "9":{
      "question":"extro 5",
      "type":"0"
   },
   "10":{
      "question":"intro 6",
      "type":"1"
   },
   "11":{
      "question":"intro 7",
      "type":"1"
   },
   "12":{
      "question":"Extro 6",
      "type":"1"
   },
   "13":{
      "question":"Extro 7",
      "type":"0"
   }
}
```

Stringifying the JSON returns:

```
{"0":{"question":"intro 1","type":"1"},"5":{"question":"extro 1","type":"0"},"7":{"question":"extro 3","type":"0"},"8":{"question":"extro 4","type":"0"},"9":{"question":"extro 5","type":"0"},"10":{"question":"intro 6","type":"1"},"11":{"question":"intro 7","type":"1"},"12":{"question":"Extro 6","type":"1"},"13":{"question":"Extro 7","type":"0"}}
```

Now when I try to save it into the cookies it only saves small part of the string.
Example:

```
{"0":{"question":"int
```

Every other browser saves the stringified JSON fully.

Code that saves cookie and stringifies the JSON:

```
document.cookie = 'my_cookie=' + JSON.stringify(my_json) + '; max-age=3600; path=/';
```

Comment: Cookie values can't contain spaces, which your JSON does have. Try to properly encode it using [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Cookies not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087869/javascript-cookies-not-working-in-safari)